# Android 2D Array

Tags: android

I'm trying to display the contents of an array based on `RadioButtons`. I use 2 sets of buttons. The button should point to `[x, y]` in my array. The `String` value of the array should be displayed (using a `Toast`).

Yes I'm new at this, but I've tried to pick apart several similar examples with little luck.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    String[][] tipSize = {
            {"N/A","N/A","Pink","Lt Blue","Purple","Yellow","Brown","Orange","Tan","Blue","White","Beige"},
            {"N/A","Pink","Lt Blue","Purple","Yellow","Brown","Orange","Green","Tan","Blue","White","Beige"},
            {"N/A","N/A","Pink","Purple","Turquoise","Yellow","Green","Tan","Blue","White","Red","No Tip"},
            {"Pink","Lt Blue","Purple","Yellow","Orange","Green","Tan","Blue","Red","Beige","Gray","N/A"},
            {"Pink","Lt Plue","Purple","Orange","Green","Tan","Blue","White","Beige","Black","Gray","N/A"},
            {"Pink","Lt Blue","Yellow","Brown","Orange","Green","Tan","Blue","White","Beige","Black","N/A"},
            {"Pink","Lt Blue","Yellow","Brown","Tan","Blue","White","Red","Beige","Black","No Tip","N/A"},
            {"Pink","Lt Blue","Purple","Yellow","Orange","Green","Tan","Blue","Red","Beige","Gray","N/A"},
    };

private RadioGroup dispenser,ounce_pg;
private RadioButton disp,o_pg;
String tip = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button finishBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    finishBtn.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {      
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            MainActivity.this.showit(); 
        }
    });     
}

protected void showit() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    disp = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.dispenser);
    o_pg = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.ounce_pg);
    tip = String tipSize [disp,o_pg];
    // tip is the displayed answer (Color of tip), tipSize[][] is the Array, disp is RadioButton 1 - o_pg is Radio Button 2 values. 

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity(),tip,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I knew the syntax was wrong, but I left it to try and show to show the direction I was looking. 
Appreciate you help.

Comment: If the syntax is wrong, what are your compiler errors?

Answer (score 0):

This line has many problems:

```
 tip = String tipSize [disp,o_pg];
```

1. `[disp,o_pg]` should be `[disp][o_pg]` since accessing a 2D array is done through `array [x][y]`
2. `String tipSize` doesn't make sense, you can't declare a type here. If you did `(String)` it would be a cast, and that would be alright (but it would be redundant since you have a `String` array - casting into a `String` from a `String` doesn't do anything).
3. `disp` and `o_pg` should be `int`.

This is because when accessing indexes, you can't pass an Object to the array, the array won't "search" for you. This means that you need to figure out what positions you want to access and pass those off. Also keep in mind indexes start at `0`, not `1`.

A compilable example is:

```
tip = tipSize [0][0]; //first element of the first array ("N/A")
```

Comment: When the RadioButton passes a value, is it the @id value or can you set the value for each radio button, then "case check" the value? Also, is the value passed as a String or Int? Having troubles when I "int a RadioButton" or converting it to a String.

Comment: @user2152750 *When the RadioButton passes a value* please elaborate. When it is clicked? You can use an [`OnCheckedChangedListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener.html) to get the Id of the RadioButton if it is part of a RadioGroup or use an `OnClickListener` if it is alone. Then, you will have to compare the id to figure out what position you want (eg `if (R.id.button = view.getId()) String s = tipSize [0][0];` Also, you should read up on [Arrays.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Comment: @user2152750 if you found my answer helpful, you should [accept it by clicking the hollowed out checkmark so it turns green](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/202881). Or if you need further clarification (provided that you read my answer and the  links I posted), just leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty way is to create a simple array of strings that contain a delimited string that groups the second values together then use split function which itself returns a string array to get the individual values.

```
String [] allTips = {"a;b;c", "d;e;f"};
String [] sometips = alltips[1].split(";")
String tip = sometips[2];
```

Would result in the letter `f`